# Order of execution of statements in Nodejs event emitter program

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronous, eventemitter, order-of-execution

I tried the following NodeJs example:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

var fun1 = (msg) => {
    console.log("Message from fun1: " + msg);
};
var fun2 = (msg) => {
    console.log("Message from fun2: " + msg);
};

eventEmitter.on('myEvent', fun1);
eventEmitter.on('myEvent', fun1);
eventEmitter.on('myEvent', fun2);

eventEmitter.removeListener('myEvent', fun1);
eventEmitter.emit('myEvent', "Event occurred");
console.log(eventEmitter.listenerCount('myEvent'));
eventEmitter.removeAllListeners('myEvent');
console.log(eventEmitter.listenerCount('myEvent'));

eventEmitter.emit('myEvent', "Event occurred");
```

Output is:

Message from fun1: Event occurred

Message from fun2: Event occurred

2

0

Please help me in understanding the output, as according to my expectation the line 'Message from fun2: Event occurred' shouldn't have been printed, as I've called removeAllListeners before it. And, Event emitter functions are called synchronously. Also, if Event emitter functions are really executed in synchronous manner, why are all the console logs getting printed at the very end?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see anything unexpected. You add three listeners, but then remove one. Upon the first `.emit(…)`, there are two listeners registered – `fun1` and `fun2` – and you get the two "Message from …" logs. Then you count listeners; there's two of them, so you get `2`. Then you remove all listeners. When you count them again there are no any, so you get `0`. Finally, since there are no listeners left, the next `.emit(…)` doesn't trigger any logs.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs docs say

> If any single listener has been added multiple times to the listener
> array for the specified eventName, then removeListener() must be
> called multiple times to remove each instance.

That's why it's still printing count as 2. Because there still are two listeners active for event "myevent" "fun1" and "fun2".

The answer to your last question is `eventEmitter.emit` is blocking(synchronous) code. And you see all the logs to the console in the end.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, But, your answer doesn't apply over here, since I have used removeAllListeners the second time, not removeListener. the question still remains... why 'Message from fun2: Event occurred' is getting printed at all and, why all console logs are executed at the very end?

Comment: the last Paragraph of the highlighted text answers your question. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You emitted the event *before* removing all the listeners. So, the listeners triggered, then were removed.